# pytest only executing the last test defined in a module/file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

pytest never fails regardless of the assertions being done in first method. The same behavior is observed when I change the order of methods also. It fails only if I change something in the last method's assertions.

````
from cpu import CPU

@pytest.fixture
def cpu():
    return CPU()

def test_00e0(cpu):
    cpu.sp = 0xa
    cpu.stack[cpu.sp] = 0x220
    cpu.pc = 0x200
    cpu.i_00ee()
    assert cpu.sp == 0x9
    assert cpu.pc == 0x220

def test_00e0(cpu):
    cpu.display[0][0] = 1
    cpu.i_00e0()
    assert sum([sum(x) for x in cpu.display]) == 0
    assert cpu.draw_flag == True```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your test methods have the same name, so the 2nd is overwriting the 1st. Give them different names and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to work on my focus. I feel like a dumbhead now.

Comment: No need to feel like that. I recognised the problem so quickly because I've made the same mistake myself - more than once. :-)